# Laravel 4, view composers against @include

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I noticed if I pass a second parameter to @include like this:

```
@include('sidebars.pages', array('categories' => Category::all()))
```

Then it is possible to replicate the concept of render partials within views and render partials within partials like in Rails.

Do I still need view composers with this functionality?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that may be possible it's not the documented use of `@include`. I'd use caution when doing it like that, and personally, I wouldn't be calling a model within your view. Bind the data you require from your route or controller. Make use of a presenter to perform any presentation logic to keep your views absolutely clean.

`@include` injects all currently defined variables into the nested partial view. So if you bound all the categories to the parent view, then used `@include('sidebars.pages')`, that view would also have the categories bound to it.

Comment: Ok, thank you Mr. Lewis, I'll play with presenters and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try View Composers to bind data to views. Works best for partial views

```
// View Composer Example
View::composer(array('sidebars.pages'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('categories', Categories::all());

});

@include('sidebars.pages')
```

Comment: Hello, where would the view composers live? Could it be in a composers.php file inside the app's root? I don't understand if they have to live in the controller, since they must be available anywhere.

Comment: You can create a folder to hold your view composers and include it start/global.php or just have it within in your app/routes.php file.

Comment: Ok Mr. mogetutu, I appreciate your answer and comment. Please could you tell me what happens if I need to pass parameters to a class method inside the view composer? Such as `Blog_model::recent($post->category->id, 5)`

Comment: how are you accessing the
    $post->category->id
is it via the url? and are you using L3 or L4?

Comment: L4, $post->category->id comes from $post = Post::find($id) in the controller, $id comes from the url, sidebars.pages doesn't have a controller.

Comment: You can try sessions or caching the variables you are trying to access and accessing them inside the view composer.