# Accessing errors in a controller from a redirect Laravel

Tags: validation, view, controller, laravel-4

As you may expect, when validation fails, I created a redirect.

```
return Redirect::to('search')->withErrors($v->messages())
```

I can access it in the view with out a problem, but I would like to do something different.  I have an ErrorPartial.blade.php, which I would like to be passed to my search view.

```
return View::make('search.searchForm')
        ->with('title', 'Search Page')
        ->with('components', Subject::select('Component')->distinct()->get())
        ->with('measurementRow',$measurementRow)
        ->with('races', Race::parseRaceTable())
        ->with('errorPartial', View::make('errorPartial')
                ->with('errors',$v->messages())
                ->render())
        ;
```

The Problem is I don't have access to $v in this controller function.  Can I access the errors that are going to be passed to the view some how?  I've tried this:

```
return Redirect::to('search')->withErrors($v->messages())
            ->with('v', $v);
```

But I get this error.

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

I could just create the Partial view in my search view but I was wondering if their was a way to do it this way.   If anyone knows which would be more efficient or GPP then I wouldn't mind knowing that as well.

Thanks

Comment: Include the partial from the view. When you pass `errors` they will be available to the partial as well.

Comment: Is this the efficient way to do it/ do you know if it even possible to do it the other way, accessing the errors in the controller and passing the view a partial view.  And do you know if just creating the partial in the view is GPP (Good programming practice)

Comment: As long as the view or partial doesn't know where data is coming from, like calling a model within them, you should be fine regarding GPP. Please take a look in a previous question of mine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092045/laravel-4-view-composers-against-include

Comment: Your comment lead me to http://laravel.com/docs/responses which lead me to http://laravel.com/docs/session . In my Controller I can do this: $errors = Session::get('errors'), allowing me to pass it to a partial view.  TY

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering the question to close it as an open question.

Laravel stores the errors in the Session, which can be access like so:

```
$errors = Session::get('errors');
```

Comment: Not quite. You cannot call $errors->any() is there is not errors, you will get `Call to a member function any() on null` when in the blade this will work without errors.

Answer (score 12):

Laravel stores the errors in the Session.

And all the functions available in blade are coming from ViewErrorBag class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag;
...
$errors = session()->get('errors', app(ViewErrorBag::class));
```

This approach is preferred because it returns empty error bag if there is no errors in the session. It means that you can call `$errors->any()` on this object without expecting to have an error saying

> Call to a member function any() on null

You can always find an implementation in source code following this advice

> The `$errors` variable is bound to the view by the  `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware, which is provided by the `web` middleware group. When this middleware is applied an `$errors` variable will always be available in your views, allowing you to conveniently assume the `$errors` variable is always defined and can be safely used.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: Great answer as it's "The Laravel Way." This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another option. That gets the error key from the default bag of messages.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

public function tranfers(Request $request) {
    ...
    // test the error exists
    $has_tranfer_error = (Session::get('errors') && Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->has('insufficient_funds'));
    ...
}

public function make_transfer(Request $request) {
    ...
    // Add the error
    return back()->withErrors(['insufficient_funds' => 'The balance is too low to make a transfer'])->withInput();
}
```